# Elemental x86 NASM Assembly - Why can't a byte label (created with db) be directly moved to a register, while arrays can?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm studying x86 Assembly with NASM,so I started by the basics. I created the code below and wanted to understand its output:

```
section .data
    msg db 'Testing', 0xA
    size db 8
    array db 21, 22, 17, 3

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; sys_WRITE the string
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, [size]
    int 0x80

    ; Exit - Return code is the first element of array
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, [array]
    int 0x80
```

This is the output:

```
Testing
.shstrtab.text.data
 %
```

I tried to define the size of the string in a Byte in the `.data` section, so it gives this output. I already figured out that it happens because, when I load a byte to the `edx` register, which is of size `dword`, some garbage stays in the remaining bits. (The solution is just to declare `size` as `dd`, but that's not what this is about).

But I wanted to understand, why it doesn't happen with the array? When I check with `echo $?`, the value is `21`. Shouldn't it be garbage?

I'm trying to understand this topic in a elemental level, I'm aware of the solution, but I don't know why the above happens.

Can someone explain? Thank you!

(The `%` is probably because I'm using a theme of Oh-My-Zsh)

Comment: `mov edx, [size]` loads 4 bytes, including 3 bytes of the string as the high 24 bits of the 32-bit integer size.  If you wanted to load a byte, use `movzx edx, byte [size]`.  It does happen with the array, too, as you'd see with a debugger or with `strace ./a.out`, but Unix exit statuses are truncated to 8 bits.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info including the section at the bottom on using debuggers.